# Does cout object remain a single instance, i.e. it never gets copied?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream, cout

Is cout ever copied implicitly?

For example, is the cout object passed to the second overloaded operator in the code below, and the cout object inside its implementation are the same objects or is one a copy of cout?

My understanding is that the first implementation is correct because the << operator works for any ostream object, e.g. it will work for ofstream objects for writing to files.

```
//First implementation
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt)
{
    os << dt.mo << '/' << dt.da << '/' << dt.yr;
    return os;
}

//Second implementation
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt)
{
    cout << dt.mo << '/' << dt.da << '/' << dt.yr;
    return cout;
}

//using second implementation on object date
cout<<date;
```

Comment: I see only references all over. I expect that cout and its class is non copyable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example doesn't copy any `ostream`, you use references everywhere. If you look at [std::cout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) you can see that it is noncopyable ([here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator%3D))

Answer (score 1):

`std::istream` and `std::ostream` objects cannot be copied. Since `std::cout` is an `ostream` object (its type is derived from `std::ostream`), it cannot be copied.